# Detecting connected watch version

Tags: android, wear-os

According to the [Android Wear 2.0 guide](https://developer.android.com/wear/preview/features/standalone-apps.html#planning_apps), Android Wear 2 apps will be installed separately, one from the Play Store on the phone and one from the Play Store on the watch, unlike Android Wear 1.x apps which are packaged together

So guidelines suggest that app should notify user if companion application is required, but not installed on the connected device.

However, not all watches will get 2.0 upgrade and some will stay at 1.x. Those watches install apps companion automatically and if one is missing, it just means app takes a while to install through Bluetooth connection. Displaying "install companion app" notification would be meaningless on these watches as there is nothing user can do to speed up the process (there is on Play Store on older watches).

Now, the issue is that I can't find a way to display warning if connected 2.x watch does not have the app and at the same time not displaying the warning if connected watch is running 1.x.

Is there a good way to distinguish between the two different connected Android Wear versions?

Comment: AFAIK not all wear devices can support the version 2.0. Not every existing Android Wear watch will be updated and supported by 2.0, but Google says most of the recent models will be. Certain features, such as Android Pay, require specific hardware, so not all models will support them. Here are the [lists of devices that supports android wear 2.0](http://www.theverge.com/2016/12/22/14057656/google-smartwatch-android-wear-2-0-launch). For more information, check this [thread](https://9to5google.com/2016/05/27/list-of-android-wear-watches-getting-the-android-wear-2-0-update/)

Comment: @KENdi Yes this is exactly the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not a good way to do this right now. It's been discussed a couple of times on the Wear developers G+ community, and the best we came up with is:

1. Go ahead and send the `RemoteIntent` to open the Play store.
2. Attach a `RemoteIntent.ResultReceiver` when you do so.
3. If the watch is running Wear 1.x, this will return with a `resultCode` of `RESULT_FAILED`, and you can show your user a message accordingly.

This is obviously not ideal; it involves a useless step (trying to open the Play store) for 1.x users, and there's also no way to distinguish any other possible failure modes. But as of today, it's the best we have.

Discussions:

https://plus.google.com/+SterlingUdell/posts/XJZ8mAsaZ8B
https://plus.google.com/u/0/+SterlingUdell/posts/WWBVxjcD7vT

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links, I did not know there was Google+ community with this discussion already present!